# ExtJS: displayfield with same style as textfield

Tags: css, extjs

I'm using xtype **displayfield** for fields which act as link and **displayfield** renders html ok. It works fine. I would like to use a same style for **displayfield** as for **textfield** (especially because of border).

Could you tell me the simplest way to achieve it? I've tried **fieldCls**, **baseCls** etc. with various prefixes but didn't find working solution.

Here my last test, could you tell me what's wrong with it?

```
Ext.create('Ext.form.Panel', {
    bodyPadding: 10,
    defaultType: 'textfield',
    fieldDefaults: {
        labelAlign: 'right',
        labelWidth: 150
    },
    renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
    standardSubmit: true,
    title: 'Form',
    width: 400,
    items: [
    {
        fieldCls: 'x-form-text',
        fieldLabel: 'Displayfield with link',
        name: 'field01',
        value: 'Some text <a href=http://www.yoururl.com>www.yoururl.com</a>',
        xtype: 'displayfield'
    },{
        fieldLabel: 'Textfield',
        name: 'field02',
        value: 'default',
        xtype: 'textfield' 
    }]
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Ext.create('Ext.form.Panel', {
    bodyPadding: 10,
    defaultType: 'textfield',
    fieldDefaults: {
        labelAlign: 'right',
        labelWidth: 150
    },        
    renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
    standardSubmit: true,
    title: 'Form',
    width: 400,
    items: [
    {
        fieldBodyCls: 'x-form-trigger-wrap-default x-form-text x-form-text-default',
        fieldLabel: 'Displayfield with link',
        name: 'field01',
        value: 'Some text <a href=http://www.yoururl.com>www.yoururl.com</a>',
        xtype: 'displayfield'
    },{
        fieldLabel: 'Textfield',
        name: 'field02',
        value: 'default',
        xtype: 'textfield' 
    }]
});
```

Comment: thank you very much, that classes render expected output, I'll use it with config fieldCls, works better for me as fieldBodyCls